# Proving that $ \frac{1}{\sin(45°)\sin(46°)}+\frac{1}{\sin(47°)\sin(48°)}+...+\frac{1}{\sin(133°)\sin(134°)}=\frac{1}{\sin(1°)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I would like to show that the following trigonometric sum

$$ \frac{1}{\sin(45°)\sin(46°)}+\frac{1}{\sin(47°)\sin(48°)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sin(133°)\sin(134°)}$$

telescopes to $$\frac{1}{\sin(1°)}$$

We have:
$$\begin{align}
\sin(45°)\sin(46°)&=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(1°)+\sin(1°))\\
\sin(47°)\sin(48°)&=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(1°)+\sin(5°))\\
\sin(49°)\sin(50°)&=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(1°)+\sin(9°))\\
&\ \vdots\\
\sin(133°)\sin(134°)&=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(1°)+\sin(177°))
\end{align}$$

So the sum is:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{44} &\frac{2}{\cos(1°)+\sin(1+4k)} 
 =\frac{2}{\cos(1°)+\sin(1°)}+\frac{2}{\cos(1°)+\sin(5°)}+\\
&\kern2.5in +\frac{2}{\cos(1°)+\sin(9°)}+\cdots+\frac{2}{\cos(1°)+\sin(177°)}.
\end{align}$$

Although I don't think this new expression simplifies the problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425966/finite-series-reciprocals-of-sines  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464031/find-the-sum-frac1-cos0-circ-cos1-circ-frac1-cos1-circ-cos2-cir

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(1^\circ)}{\sin(x^\circ) \sin(x+1)^\circ}=\frac{\sin((x+1)^\circ-x^\circ)}{\sin(x^\circ) \sin(x+1)^\circ}=$$
$$\frac{\sin((x+1)^\circ) \cos (x^\circ)}{\sin(x^\circ) \sin(x+1)^\circ}-\frac{\sin(x^\circ) \cos(x+1)^\circ}{\sin(x^\circ) \sin(x+1)^\circ}= \cot(x^\circ)-\cot(x+1)^\circ$$

Add them and you get your telescopic sum ;)

Comment: So the sum is: $ \frac{1}{\sin(1°)}(\cot(45°)-\cot(46°)+\cot(47°)-\cot(48°)+...+\cot(133°)-\cot(134°))$, but I can't see how it telescopes.

Comment: It gives $ \frac{1}{\sin(1°)}(\cot(45°)-\cot(90°))=\frac{1}{\sin(1°)}$, thanks!

Comment: could you guys like explain this again ;-; how did he get sin 1 in the numerator smh

Comment: @AayushPaurana Multiply the top and bottom by $\sin(1^\circ)$:$$\frac{1}{\sin(45°)\sin(46°)}+\frac{1}{\sin(47°)\sin(48°)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sin(133°)\sin(134°)}=\frac{1}{\sin(1^\circ)}\left(\frac{\sin(1^\circ)}{\sin(45°)\sin(46°)}+\frac{\sin(1^\circ)}{\sin(47°)\sin(48°)}+\cdots+\frac{\sin(1^\circ)}{\sin(133°)\sin(134°)}\right)$$

Comment: @N.S. Thanks a lot!