# Goniometric simplification

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving that $ \frac{1}{\sin(45&#176;)\sin(46&#176;)}+\frac{1}{\sin(47&#176;)\sin(48&#176;)}+&hellip;+\frac{1}{\sin(133&#176;)\sin(134&#176;)}=\frac{1}{\sin(1&#176;)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/proving-that-frac1-sin45-sin46-frac1-sin47-sin48-fr)

Simplify the following sum

$$ \frac{1}{\sin\left(1°\right)\sin\left(2°\right)} + \frac{1}{\sin \left(2°\right) \sin \left(3°\right)}   + \frac{1}{\sin\left(3°\right)\sin\left(4°\right)} + ... + \frac{1}{\sin\left(89°\right) \sin \left(90°\right)}$$

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: perhaps if you write this like $$\frac{1}{\sin(90-89)\sin(90-88)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sin(90-1)\sin(90-0)}$$

Comment: and how to proceed next?

Comment: I don't know... i'm asking myself the same, hehe. I realized this could not help anyway...

Comment: I just found a similar problem here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/proving-that-frac1-sin45-sin46-frac1-sin47-sin48-fr I can solve it now. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, thanks for pointing that hint.