# Series with cosine explanation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Would someone please explain how I would solve this problem without having to use Wolfram Alpha? This problem was originally posted on Google Plus.

[image]

Wolfram Alpha: http://wolfr.am/Z42ivS

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/proving-that-frac1-sin45-sin46-frac1-sin47-sin48-fr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum\dfrac{1}{\cos a_n\cos a_{n+1}}=\sum \dfrac{\tan a_{n+1}-\tan{a_n}}{\sin (a_{n+1}-a_n)}$

(As,$\sin(x-y)=\sin x \cos y-\sin y \cos x$)

You can finish it from here I think.