# Find sum of $\frac{1}{\sin\theta\cdot \sin2\theta} + \frac{1}{\sin2\theta\cdot \sin3\theta} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sin n \theta \sin (n+1)\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sin k\theta \sin (k+1)\theta} = \dfrac{1}{\sin\theta\cdot \sin2\theta} + \dfrac{1}{\sin2\theta\cdot \sin3\theta} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sin n \theta \sin (n+1)\theta}$$ up to $n$ terms.

I tried but in vain

Comment: "I tried but in vain". In order to help you (and not to do your homework), it is important you tell what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464031/find-the-sum-frac1-cos0-circ-cos1-circ-frac1-cos1-circ-cos2-cir

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$\dfrac{\sin{\theta}}{\sin{(k+1)\theta}\sin{(k\theta)}}=\dfrac{\sin{((k+1)\theta-k\theta)}}{\sin{(k+1)\theta}\sin{(k\theta)}}=\cot{(k\theta)}-\cot{(k+1)\theta}$$

Comment: New users who have no post history and do not show evidence of what they tried, should not receive free answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: the sum telescopes, with some careful manipulation:

$$\sin \theta = \sin((k+1)\theta - k\theta) = \sin(k+1)\theta \cos k\theta - \sin k\theta \cos (k+1)\theta.$$

Comment: Where does your answer differ from that of math110?

Comment: It differs to the extent that I don't explicitly write out the form of the telescoping terms.  I think that @math110's answer gives away too much, whereas some additional thought is required with my hint.

Comment: Anyway, the approaches are equivalent.