# $\frac{1}{\sin 8^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 16^\circ}+....+\frac{1}{\sin 4096^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 8192^\circ}=\frac{1}{\sin \alpha}$,find $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\frac{1}{\sin 8^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 16^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 32^\circ}+....+\frac{1}{\sin 4096^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 8192^\circ}=\frac{1}{\sin \alpha}$ where $\alpha\in(0,90^\circ)$,then find $\alpha$(in degree.)

---

$\frac{1}{\sin 8^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 16^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 32^\circ}+....+\frac{1}{\sin 4096^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 8192^\circ}=\frac{1}{\sin \alpha}$
$\frac{2\cos8^\circ}{\sin 16^\circ}+\frac{2\cos16^\circ}{\sin 32^\circ}+\frac{2\cos32^\circ}{\sin 64^\circ}+....+\frac{2\cos4096^\circ}{\sin 8192^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 8192^\circ}=\frac{1}{\sin \alpha}$

$\frac{2^2\cos8^\circ\cos16^\circ}{\sin 32^\circ}+\frac{2^2\cos16^\circ\cos32^\circ}{\sin 64^\circ}+\frac{2^2\cos32^\circ\cos64^\circ}{\sin 128^\circ}+....+\frac{2\cos4096^\circ}{\sin 8192^\circ}+\frac{1}{\sin 8192^\circ}=\frac{1}{\sin \alpha}$
In this way this series is getting complicated at each stage,is there any way to simplify it?Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT:

For $\sin A\ne0\iff A\ne m\pi$  where $m$ is any integer,

$$\cot A-\cot2A=\dfrac{\sin(2A-A)}{\sin2A\sin A}=\csc2A$$

Do you recognize the [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: Why 'DO' and not 'Do'?

Comment: @G-man, Please ignore the case difference. Btw could you follow my method?

Comment: Ummm..yes. But why did you feel the need to ask me that?

Comment: @G-man, I want to be sure that : my method is understandable enough

Comment: Using the telescoping series,the question boils down to $\frac{2\sin(8192-4)}{\cos(8192-4)-\cos(8192+4)}$.It does not simplify to some cosec.What should i do?@labbhattacharjee

Comment: @diya, Please re-validate your calculation

Comment: @diya, See http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2010/2010EuclidSolution.pdf   $$9 a(ii)$$

Comment: I got it,thanks.Firstly before posting this question,i expanded both sides,using Mclaurin series.$\csc x=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{6}+...$.Let $\beta=8^\circ$.Then i compared both sides to get $\frac{1}{\beta}+\frac{1}{2\beta}+\frac{1}{2^2\beta}+....+\frac{1}{2^{10}\beta}=\frac{1}{\alpha}$<br>Then using geometric series,i got $\alpha=\frac{512\beta}{1023}=\frac{4096}{1023}=4+\frac{4}{1023}$,which is approximately 4,not exactly 4.Can we use this method,if rigorous trigonometric method does not click to mind.Is it valid in such questions?@labbhattacharjee

Comment: @diya, I request you to avoid using Mclaurin series in case of such Trigonometric problems like this one or (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464031/find-the-sum-frac1-cos0-circ-cos1-circ-frac1-cos1-circ-cos2-cir) even though Mclaurin series sounds simpler to you.

Answer (score 5):

This is just the same idea as in lab bhattacharjee's answer, but using the identity from the [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula)
$$
\tan(x/2)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\tan(x/2)}-\frac1{\tan(x)}
&=\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\\
&=\frac1{\sin(x)}
\end{align}
$$
The rest is the same telescoping series
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{\sin\left(2^kx\right)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac1{\tan\left(2^{k-1}x\right)}-\frac1{\tan\left(2^kx\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac1{\tan(x/2)}-\frac1{\tan\left(2^nx\right)}
\end{align}
$$
The question has $x=8^\circ$ and $n=10$, so we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{10}\frac1{\sin\left(2^k8^\circ\right)}
&=\frac1{\tan(4^\circ)}-\frac1{\tan(8192^\circ)}\\
&=\frac1{\tan(4^\circ)}+\frac1{\tan(88^\circ)}\\
&=\frac1{\tan(4^\circ)}+\tan(2^\circ)\\
&=\frac{\cos(4^\circ)}{\sin(4^\circ)}+\frac{\sin(4^\circ)}{1+\cos(4^\circ)}\\
&=\frac{\cos(4^\circ)}{\sin(4^\circ)}+\frac{1-\cos(4^\circ)}{\sin(4^\circ)}\\
&=\frac1{\sin(4^\circ)}
\end{align}
$$