# Prove that for every natural number $n$ and for every real numbers

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that for every natural number $n$ and for every real numbers $x\neq \dfrac {k\pi}{2^t }$ $(t=0,1,....n;)$ (where $k$ is any integer)
$$\dfrac {1}{\sin 2x}+\dfrac {1}{\sin 4x}+.....+\dfrac {1}{\sin 2^n x}=\cot x-\cot 2^nx$$

Comment: I offer a proof that doesn't use the induction. If you don't understand it ,I can edit it clearly.

Comment: @Daisy, please u may edit

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591220/frac1-sin-8-circ-frac1-sin-16-circ-frac1-sin-4096-circ

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof by induction

This is true for base case $n=1$
Assume true for $n$ ...So $$\cot x-\cot2^{n+1}x=\cot x-\cot(2(2^{n}x))=\cot x-\frac12((\cot(2^nx)-\tan(2^nx))$$$$= \cot x-\frac12\cot(2^nx)+\frac12\tan(2^nx)=\cot x-\cot(2^nx)+\frac12(\cot(2^nx)+\tan(2^nx))$$
Note that

$$\frac12(\cot(2^nx)+\tan(2^nx))=\frac{1}{\sin(2^{n+1}x)}$$
where I used $\cot x +\tan x=\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x}$ and $\cot2x=\frac12(\cot x-\tan x)$

So..can you complete now?

Answer (score 0):

Since

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin 2x}=\frac{2{\cos}^2x-\cos2x}{2\sin x\cos x}=\cot x-\cot 2x,
\end{align}
then, if we regard $x$ as $2x$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin 4x}=\frac{2{\cos}^22x-\cos 4x}{2\sin 2x \cos 2x}=\cot 2x-\cot 4x.
\end{align}
Similarly, repeat the above step until $n$,
we have 
\begin{align}
LHS=\cot x-\cot 2x+\cot 2x-\cot 4x+...+\cot 2^{n-1}x-\cot 2^nx=\cot x-\cot 2^nx=RHS.
\end{align}