# Series problem involving sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that:
>
> $$
> \sum 2^{2n}\sin^4\left(a \over 2^{n}\right) =
> 4^n\sin^{2}\left(a \over 2^{n} \right) - \sin^{2}\left(a\right)
> $$

I tried converting the square power on sin by trying the half angle formula, I saw a relation between the 2 sides of equality, its like substituting n in place of n and taking square root of sin function minus putting 0 on LHS and taking square root of sine. Its just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$4^m\sin^4\dfrac a{2^m}-4^m\sin^2\dfrac a{2^m}=4^m\sin^2\dfrac a{2^m}\left(\sin^2\dfrac a{2^m}-1\right)=-4^{m-1}\left(2\sin\dfrac a{2^m}\cos\dfrac a{2^m}\right)^2$$

$$=-4^{m-1}\sin^2\dfrac a{2^{m-1}}$$

$$\implies4^m\sin^4\dfrac a{2^m}=4^m\sin^2\dfrac a{2^m}-4^{m-1}\sin^2\dfrac a{2^{m-1}}$$

Recognize the [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Set $m=1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ and add

Comment: yeah i recognised it in the final step :)

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, Do you have any confusion?

Comment: yeah..how did you think of the first step ? how did it click ?

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, Subtracted the first term of the right hand side from the final term of the left hand side

Comment: okay..that was a great approach !

Comment: why did you do that..i mean how did you think of doing this ?

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, Like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591220/frac1-sin-8-circ-frac1-sin-16-circ-frac1-sin-4096-circ, I perceived that Telescoping Series will be identified.