# Prove that: $\operatorname{cosec}(2A) + \operatorname{cosec}(4A) + \operatorname{cosec}(8A) = \cot(A) - \cot(8A) $

Tags: trigonometry

How can we prove
$\operatorname{cosec}(2A) + \operatorname{cosec}(4A) + \operatorname{cosec}(8A) = \cot(A) - \cot(8A)$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MathSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you prove $\csc 2A=\cot A-\cot2A$?

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591220/frac1-sin-8-circ-frac1-sin-16-circ-frac1-sin-4096-circ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the right side to the left.
$$cosec(2A)+cosec(4A)+cosec(8A)-cot(A)+cot(8A)=0$$
Then express the left side by sines and cosines. You get:
$$\frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{1}{sin(4A)}+\frac{1}{sin(8A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)}+\frac{cos(8A)}{sin(8A)} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{1}{sin(4A)}+\frac{1+cos(8A)}{sin(8A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{1}{sin(4A)}+\frac{2cos^2(4A)}{2sin(4A)cos(4A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{1}{sin(4A)}+\frac{cos(4A)}{sin(4A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{1+cos(4A)}{sin(4A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{2cos^2(2A)}{2sin(2A)cos(2A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{1}{sin(2A)}+\frac{cos(2A)}{sin(2A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{1+cos(2A)}{sin(2A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{2cos^2(A)}{2sin(A)cos(A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = $$
$$= \frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)}-\frac{cos(A)}{sin(A)} = 0$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: I think a hint would have been better, since the OP did not show any context in their question.