# Show that this series converges and find its sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\cosh(n)\cosh(n+1)}$$

For showing that it is convergent. I prove it by using ratio test. But for finding the value of sum. I stuck on this part.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/464031/42969 for a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh(n) \cosh (n+1)}
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(\frac{e^n + e^{-n}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{e^{n+1} + e^{-(n+1)}}{2}\right)}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\left(e^n + e^{-n}\right)\left(e^{n+1} + e^{-(n+1)}\right)}\\
&= 4 e\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{-2 n}+e^{2 n+2}+e^2+1}\\
&= \frac{4 e}{1-e^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{e^{2n+2}+1} - \frac{1}{e^{2 n}+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{4 e}{1-e^2} \left[\left(\frac{1}{e^{4}+1} + \frac{1}{e^{6}+1} + \dots\right) - \left(\frac{1}{e^{2}+1} + \frac{1}{e^{4}+1} \dots\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{4 e}{1-e^2} \left(-\frac{1}{e^2+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{4 e}{e^4-1}
\end{align}