# Finite Series - reciprocals of sines

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

Find the sum of the finite series
$$\sum _{k=1}^{k=89} \frac{1}{\sin(k^{\circ})\sin((k+1)^{\circ})}$$
This problem was asked in a test in my school.
The answer seems to be $\dfrac{\cos1^{\circ}}{\sin^21^{\circ}}$ but I do not know how. I have tried reducing it using sum to product formulae and found out the actual value and it agrees well. Haven't been successful in telescoping it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{1}{\sin k^\circ\sin(k+1)^\circ}=\frac1{\sin1^\circ}\frac{\sin (k+1-k)^\circ}{\sin k^\circ\sin(k+1)^\circ}$$
$$=\frac1{\sin1^\circ}\cdot\frac{\cos k^\circ\sin(k+1)^\circ-\sin k^\circ\cos(k+1)^\circ}{\sin k^\circ\sin(k+1)^\circ}=\frac1{\sin1^\circ}\left(\cot k^\circ-\cot(k+1)^\circ\right)$$

Can you recognize Telescoping [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) / [sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)?

Comment: @cmtappu96, observe that only $\cot1^\circ$ surviving the summation   to validate the answer

Comment: Thank you. My bad. I was trying to somehow get a factor of $\sin(k+1)-\sin(k)$ in the numerator.

Comment: @cmtappu96, welcome. Here we need the knowledge trigonometric identity and Telescoping  sum as well