Evaluating $\sum_{r=1}^{88}{(-1)^{r+1}\frac{1}{\sin^2(r+1^\circ)-\sin^2(1^\circ)}}$
I just stumbled accross this question and I am unable to move ahead in the problem.

What is the value of the following summation?
$$\sum_{r=1}^{88}{(-1)^{r+1}\frac{1}{\sin^2(r+1^\circ)-\sin^2(1^\circ)}}$$

MY APPROACH:
Step 1: Expand.
This is what I usually do when I come accross a summation till a specific number.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{88}{(-1)^{r+1} \frac{1}{\sin^2(r+1^\circ)-
\sin^2(1^\circ)}} 
&= \frac{1}{\sin^2(2^\circ)-\sin^2(1^\circ)}-\frac{1}{\sin^2(3^\circ)-\sin^2(1^\circ)} \\
&\quad+\frac{1}{\sin^2(4^\circ)-\sin^2(1^\circ)}\cdots-\frac{1}{\sin^2(89^\circ)-\sin^2(1^\circ)} \\
&= \frac{1}{[\sin(2^\circ)+\sin(1^\circ)][\sin(2^\circ)-\sin(1^\circ)]} \\
&\quad-\frac{1}{[\sin(3^\circ)+\sin(1^\circ)][\sin(3^\circ)-\sin(1^\circ)]} \\
&\quad+\frac{1}{[\sin(4^\circ)+\sin(1^\circ)][\sin(4^\circ)-\sin(1^\circ)]} \cdots \\
&\quad-\frac{1}{[\sin(89^\circ)+\sin(1^\circ)][\sin(89^\circ)-\sin(1^\circ)]} 
\end{align}$$
Now, I think I have to apply $\sin(90^\circ-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$, but I'm not very sure about where and how to apply this.
Tell me if I have to. And if so, where.
All solutions are encouraged. :)
Also, the answer given was $\dfrac{\cot(2^\circ)}{\sin(2^\circ)}$.
Tell me if this is correct.
If so, how do you reach to that answer?
Thank you.

Plugging it into Wolfram alpha and then manually evaluating the given answer they check out to be the same. This might involve the Pythagorean identity as well, don't have a full solution yet

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425966/finite-series-reciprocals-of-sines

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac1{\sin^2A-\sin^2B}&=\frac1{\sin (A+B)\sin(A-B)}\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\sin(A-B)}{\sin2B}}_{=1}\frac1{\sin (A+B)\sin(A-B)}\\
&=\frac{\cot(A-B)-\cot(A+B)}{\sin2B}
\end{aligned}$$
so that with $A=k+1$, $B=1$ (in degrees) one obtains:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{k=1}^{88}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sin^2A-\sin^2B}=\frac1{\sin2}\sum_{k=1}^{88}(-1)^{k+1}\left[\cot k-\cot(k+2)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin2}[(\cot1-\cot3)-(\cot2-\cot4)+\cdots+(\cot87-\cot89)-(\cot88-\cot90)]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin2}[\cot1-\cot2-\cot89+\cot90]=\frac{\cot2}{\sin2},
\end{aligned}$$
where in the last equality we used the identity $\cot x-\tan x=2\cot2x$.
