# The integer part of $\sum_{k=0}^{44}\frac{1}{\cos(k^\circ)\cos((k+1)^\circ)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

> What is the integer part of the number $$\sum_{k=0}^{44}\frac{1}{\cos (k^\circ)\cos((k+1)^\circ)}$$

I tried to solve it using partial fractions but could not get a result. Please help me out.

Comment: Your equation does not make sense. Please correct it

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cp0rboxr67

Comment: Is it $\cos(k)$ or $\cos(k^\circ)$?

Comment: @N.S $\cos(k^\circ)$ according to original version of this question.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/proving-that-frac1-sin45-sin46-frac1-sin47-sin48-fr/95299#95299

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice for any $a < b$, we have

$$\tan b - \tan a = \frac{\sin b\cos a - \sin a\cos b}{\cos b\cos a} = \frac{\sin(b-a)}{\cos b\cos a}$$
This implies
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{44} \frac{1}{\cos(k^\circ)\cos((k+1)^\circ)}
&= \frac{1}{\sin 1^\circ}\sum_{k=0}^{44} \left(\tan((k+1)^\circ) - \tan(k^\circ)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sin 1^\circ}\left(\tan(45^\circ) - \tan(0^\circ)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi}{180}} \approx 57.29868849855018
\end{align}$$
The integer we seek is $57$.

Answer (score -1):

Playing around.

Let
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\cos(k)\cos(k+1)}
$.

Looking at the sum in Wolfy,
it peaks at about 12
and has a period of about 22
with 7 peaks.
The extreme values 
are about $\pm 10$.
This is probably due to
$\pi \approx \frac{22}{7}$.

In particular,
$s(44) \approx 1.9$
so the integer part is 1.

Also,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1}{\cos(k)}-\frac1{\cos(k+1)}
&=\frac{\cos(k+1)-\cos(k)}{\cos(k)\cos(k+1)}\\
&=-2\frac{\sin(k+\frac12)\sin(\frac12)}{\cos(k)\cos(k+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

but this doesn't seem to help much.

Can't think of
anything else.

Comment: I did the same but I was struck here.

Comment: Integer part is between 50–56